# How to change the language inside the app

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my app, I need to change the language.  I need to add a button that will enable  Change of the language. how to implement it on xamarin forms.

I need to change language within the app not with the phone setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xamarin.Forms Localization:
Suppose you want to change language to French then its code is: `fr-FR`

1. Add folder named `Resources` in your project
2. Inside that folder add resource file of your required language.[here there will be two files, one is default and another is of french][`ApplicationResource.resx` and `ApplicationResource.fr.resx`]
3. Add value in that file

For french file:

`<data name="DescriptionTitle" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Description</value>
    <comment>DescriptionTitle</comment>
  </data>`

For default file:

`<data name="DescriptionTitle" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Description</value>
    <comment>DescriptionTitle</comment>
  </data>`

In your xaml file:

Add reference
 `xmlns:resource="clr-namespace:yourProject.Resources"`

Use inside control:

`<Label Text="{x:Static resource:ApplicationResource.DescriptionTitle}"/>`

On your button click event write this:
`ApplicationResources.Culture =  new CultureInfo("fr-FR");`

This way it will change language for whole application.

You can refer this for more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=windows

Hope this may solve your issue.